# How to stop a panel's children from exceeding the bounds if the panel's MaxWidth is set?

Tags: wpf, layout, wpf-controls

I have observed this problem in `Grids` and `StackPanels`, it might apply to other panels too, consider the following Xamls:

```
<Grid MaxWidth="200">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label>Title:</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

and

```
<StackPanel MaxWidth="200">
    <Label>Title:</Label>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

(Edit: I have several such variable blocks that is why i don't set the `MaxWidth` of the `TextBox` itself)

Of course what i want is that upon text input the `TextBox` does not grow any bigger if the parent's `MaxWidth` is reached, this however does not happen, the panel resizes till it reaches the `MaxWidth` and the `TextBox` shoots outside of bounds.

If the second grid-column has no Width defined (one star by default) the `TextBox` will not grow since it just takes all the available space so the text scrolls like i want it too but this panel is an item in a `ToolBar` and if the `ToolBar` is in a horizontal `ToolBarTray` this setting causes an instant overflow.

Any ideas on how to get the TextBox to not go out of bounds?

**Edit:** The answers (probably) work in normal scenarios but the ToolBar somehow screws my layout over, for one thing my controls always get pushed into the ToolBar overflow area for whatever reason and contents that before stretched inside a Grid-cell no longer do so. Since my original question was how to prevent this internal overflow (and not how to cope with the ToolBar's peculiarities) i'll just leave it at that.

Comment: What I've found is that StackPanel doesn't give any sizing suggestions to its children and purely arranges the children in a stack.  For this kind of scenario I either use a Grid (with parameters suggested in an answer below) or a DockPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the second ColumnDefinition Width to *, set the textbox HorizontalAlignment to stretch and TextWrapping to Wrap to get the effect you want (see XAML below)

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid" MinWidth="200" MaxWidth="200">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label>Title:</Label>
    <TextBox Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

Edit: You can create a Style to be applied to text boxes so that you don't have to keep setting the same properties again for other text boxes.

Comment: Does not solve my problem because of the ToolBar but it's an answer to the original question i guess.

Comment: I just tested my changes in a ToolBar and it does overflow as you say - There doesn't appear to be a property to disable this; I think this would require a custom ControlTemplate. Instead of a ToolBar why not just dock a Panel to the top of your form and change the border and background properties so that it looks like one?

Comment: The point of ToolBars is to be able to rearrange them inside a ToolBarTray, if that wasn't what i needed i would not use ToolBars since they are a pain in general.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
    <DockPanel MaxWidth="200">
        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">Title:</Label>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </DockPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sadly this does not work with my ToolBar setup either, see my note at the end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure if it's not contradict to your application requirements but did you try to set the the MaxLength of the TextBox ?

Comment: That is not an option because there are several of these Label-TextBox pairs and i want them all to stop at the right edge automatically without measuring how much space each one can get.